# What tasks does an installer perform? (Single file)

Tags: .net, windows, deployment, installation

Assuming a single executable and nothing else.

What I have so far:

1. Put the file somewhere.
2. Create a start menu shortcut.
3. Install .net.

Is there anything else?

Comment: Maybe some registry entry/uninstaller so that you can uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an installer is much complicated, if you analyze the backend operations it performs. Copying some files and creating some shortcuts its the easy part, but an installer must also handle correctly failed installations (i.e. rollback all the system changes), cases when it tries to update a file in used by the system, UAC elevation, patching, application/system requirements, etc...

There have been people that already analyzed all these cases and solution were implemented, you should not try to re-invent the wheel, there are tools (free and paid) that can generate you an installer in just a couple of minutes, and also integrate with Windows development IDEs.

Since you have a simple installer [Wix](http://wixtoolset.org/) should be more than enough for you, its the best free option on the market, very powerful and versatile. It has the disadvantage of being script based, but your installer you can find a lot of examples. There also [paid tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer#Tools), if you don't like scripting.

Please use the existent APIs for basic installing needs, it is a waste of your time to try writing your own installer from scratch. And even if you do, you will never get an installer package as solid and standards-compliant as it would happen if you would use professional tools to build the installer.